# Custom Classes not appearing in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-storyboard

My project is using a storyboard that has been working great so far. However, just yesterday something very strange happened - here are the details:

- Any new IBOutlets or IBActions I create aren't listed under "Referencing Outlets" in the Connections inspector.
- If I remove any of my existing referencing connections in the storyboard - they disappear completely from the list and I can't re-connect them.
- If I try to set the custom class under the identity inspector, I can't see any of my classes being pre-populated or appearing in the dropdown list.

I have tried cleaning, cleaning derived data, quitting XCode and restarting my computer but no luck! This problem hasn't affected any other projects though.

If anyone has any thoughts on how this could be resolved that would be amazing!

Kind regards,
Jeremy

Comment: this sounds really weird, you can always upgrade or install a fresh copy thats probably faster then looking for alternatives

Comment: Have you cleaned the build folder? (Hold option while you click "Clean")

Comment: Yeah that's right - sorry, I said 'clean derived data' instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by restarting my computer again!

I think that you must need to clean your build folder and then restart.

Thanks guys for your comments!

Comment: It does not help in my case. Don't know what to do!!(

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this answer to everywhere! None of this solution worked for me!

All you have to do is:

**Step 1**: Check your selected class have the right "**Subclass**" when you have *created* this class for a storyboard reference!

**Step 2**: If the **subclass** is wrong, **delete** this class and create  it again with right Subclass, for example it can be UIView or UITabelView or UIViewController or anything else!

[I have recreated this class with right subclasses and it worked for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0YUP.png)
[image: I have recreated this class with right subclasses and it worked for me]

Answer (score 0):

The new Xcode 14 has a toolchain feature which we recently used .. and I ran into this same problem without noticing I have to change it back .. so if like me you changed the toolchain for some purpose change it back to Xcode and force restart Xcode